# How can I add one word to another word in a string to an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I have a string which is something like this:

`apples1h7s5e47epearshrrdjhrdjdrjapples15r4h775h47pearshrmbaewv4kg0kapples15hrs477sr547pears`

and I want to get from the string all of the words which are apples to pears and put them in an array. 
So the output would be:

`apples1h7s5e47epears, apples15r4h775h47pears, apples15hrs477sr547pears`

Comment: Sorry, duplicate-closers, do you ever read the question and the content of the 'marked duplicate' when you press the button? This is nonsense!! He didn't ask 'how to find something with regexp'! Pay more attention, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this

```
const string = "apples1h7s5e47epears hrrdjhrdjdrj apples15r4h775h47pears hrmbaewv4kg0k apples15hrs477sr547pears"

const data = string.match(/(apples\w*)/g)
console.log(data)
```

I hope this might help

Answer (score 1):

Here i split it up, and filter it.

Keep in mind this wont work in IE, you will need an Polyfill

```js
let bigString = "apples1h7s5e47epears hrrdjhrdjdrj apples15r4h775h47pears hrmbaewv4kg0k apples15hrs477sr547pears";

let result = bigString.split(" ").filter(el => el.startsWith("apples") && el.endsWith("pears"))

console.log(result);
```

`startsWith` Polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
  };
}
```

`endsWith` Polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

Comment: Almost - the requirement was 'starts with apples and ends with pears'

Comment: @AndreasDolk answer updated, should work now i guess...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest parsing the string as a character array first then look for the combination of words and add them to another array you defined. Thats perhaps the most straight forward way to go about but there maybe easier ways out there I mainly work with C# so I am not sure.